# Incorrect UTF-8 accents in vi/vim on OpenBSD 6.2

Tags: openbsd, vi, unicode

After a default install of OpenBSD 6.2 with FVWM, I open an xterm on the FVWM GUI, with normal user, create a test file:

```
$ echo 'árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép' > test.txt
$ echo 'ÁRVÍZTŰRŐ TÜKÖRFÚRÓGÉP' >> test.txt
$ 
$ cat test.txt
árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép
ÁRVÍZTŰRŐ TÜKÖRFÚRÓGÉP
$ 
$ locale
LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_ALL=
$ 
$ env | grep -i locale
XTERM_LOCALE=C
$
```

and the problem is that if I open the testfile with vi:

[image]

and with vim, a little better, but still problems with uppercase and a few lowercase:

[image]

Tried to set all the locale variables to "hu_HU.UTF-8" but didn't helped. What am I missing?

Back in the older days, afaik, there was "uxterm" to have UTF-8 support, but now, it looks like it is not in OpenBSD anymore.

Comment: uxterm is just a shell script that calls xterm.

Comment: Does it work as expected if you run `LC_ALL=hu_HU.UTF-8 vim testfile`?

Comment: If OP hasn't installed the locales, that won't help :-)

Comment: that's how `vi` behaves on OpenBSD 6.2 for unicode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make sure that you are using the proper locale, then you will be able the see the correct characters in `vim` and in `nvi`, but not in `vi`.

```
$ LC_CTYPE=hu_HU.UTF-8 vim test.txt
```

or,

```
$ export LC_CTYPE=hu_HU.UTF-8
$ vim test.txt
```

In fact, it works (in `vim`/`nvi`) with the `en_US.UTF-8` locale as well. OpenBSD's `vi` is not UTF-8 aware.

[image: Vim showing the text file]

This was tested on OpenBSD-current (pre-6.3) with the base system's `vi` as well as with `vim` and `nvi` from ports. The picture shows Vim from OpenBSD ports (`vim-8.0.1255p0-no_x11`) running in PuTTY from a Windows host, but I tested it successfully in OpenBSD's FVWM with the standard `xterm` too. The locale is `hu_HU.UTF-8` in the picture. Setting the locale to `C` gives the same result as you show in the question.

The correct locale could be set in your `.xsession` file (or `.xinitrc`, depending on whether you log in from `xenodm` or start X11 with `startx` on the console):

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

fwvm & wmpid=$!
xterm &

wait "$wmpid"
```

(or something similar)

Note that the `LC_ALL` and/or `LC_CTYPE` variable needs to be exported.

---

Regarding `uxterm`: `uxterm` seems to have been removed after the release of OpenBSD 6.0.

The commit message (from Mon, 24 Oct 2016 13:55:37) simply reads

```
Stop providing the uxterm and koi8rxterm shell scripts.
Requested by schwarze@ agreed naddy@
```

There is, however, a port called [`rxvt-unicode`](https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/ports/x11/rxvt-unicode/) which provides the `urxvt` utility.

Comment: also I was using a "ISO-8859 text"... only/at least the "Non-ISO extended-ASCII text" works with the mentioned export LC_CTYPE

Answer (score 1):

The OpenBSD version of vi doesn't support UTF-8 yet. Vim will work fine but you need a terminal with support for UTF-8 and the correct locales. I don't remember how many locales includes OpenBSD, so try with `en_US.UTF-8` as `LC_CTYPE`.